# Value overlapping issue in barchart of PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

In the chart section of the image, the value 1 is overlapping with value 19. I have used bar chart here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Buddy its because the 1 value of above bar in stacked bar is low and you are drawing values inside bars. All you can do is try shifting values above bars but this can also overlap but give it a try. For that do the following:

```
chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
```

Or you can change the color of values text as of colors of bars to differentiate for that you have to move values above bars so one can see that.